# What's the easiest way to get the "Smash Brothers" achievement in System Protocol One?

Tags: achievements, system-protocol-one

To get the "Smash Brothers" achievement, you need to get two *adjacent*, *fully-charged* Compressors to fire at the same time.  I haven't been able to do this.  Is there some setup that makes it easier for two adjacent Compressors to fire simultaneously?

Things I've tried:
(c is compressor, C is big compressor, . is a path, x is a wall.)

1) A bunch of Compressors in a row, and hoping against hope.

```
c.x
c.x
c.x
c.x
```

2) A big compressor behind a small compressor, so their blast areas overlap and start at about the same place.

```
Cc.x
Cc.x
```

3) Putting two compressors right next to the virus-entry place. (E = entry)

```
xE.x
cc.x
```